# Update hidden inputs based on drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I work mostly in PHP, and have just started  playing with javascript. I have a form that when a drop down is selected for a province, it updates 2 hidden input fields. One with a dollar value, and one with the value sent from the drop down.

I have this working, but I am sure there are more elegant ways to do it. Any guidance to eliminate some redundancy would be great.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeHiddenInput(objDropDown) {
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "X") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = 2600;
        $('#customButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#customButton2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "AB") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('AB', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "AB";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "BC") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('BC', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "BC";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "MB") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('MB', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "MB";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "NB") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('NB', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "NB";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "NL") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('NL', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "NL";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "NS") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('NS', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "NS";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "ON") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('ON', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "ON";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "PE") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('PE', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "PE";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "QC") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('QC', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "QC";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "SK") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('SK', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "SK";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "NT") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('NT', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "NT";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "NU") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('NU', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "NU";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value === "YT") {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("amount");
        objHidden.value = <?php echo getFees('YT', 'sprice', $price); ?>;

        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("province");
        objHidden2.value = "YT";

        $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<select required name="prov" id="myselect" class="dropit" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">
    <option value="X">Select ship to province</option>
    <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
    <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
    <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
    <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
    <option value="NL">Newfoundland/Labrador</option>
    <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
    <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
    <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
    <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
    <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
    <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
    <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
    <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="province" id="province" value="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do is add an attribute price to each option tag, then change the script to this (Run this snippet to see your desired result)

```js
function changeHiddenInput(objDropDown)
   {
    var selectedOption = objDropDown.children[objDropDown.selectedIndex];
    var price = selectedOption.getAttribute('price');
    var province = objDropDown.value;
    document.getElementById('province').value = province;
    document.getElementById('amount').value = price;
    console.log('Province changed to: '+province);
    console.log('Price changed to: '+price);
        
        $('#customButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#customButton2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required name="prov" id="myselect" class="dropit" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">
    <option price="2600" value="X">Select ship to province</option>
    <option price="455" value="AB">Alberta</option>
    <option price="4212" value="BC">British Columbia</option>
    <option price="5445" value="MB">Manitoba</option>
    <option price="445" value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
    <option price="3434" value="NL">Newfoundland/Labrador</option>
    <option price="3433" value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
    <option price="3434" value="ON">Ontario</option>
    <option price="434" value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
    <option price="333" value="QC">Quebec</option>
    <option price="3434" value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
    <option price="2323" value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
    <option price="23" value="NU">Nunavut</option>
    <option price="2323" value="YT">Yukon</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="province" id="province" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code. Hope it will help.

- Use jQuery to attach the combobox "change" event, remove   `onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)"`event from select tag in html.
  Just to make it clean.
- Clear the "province" and "amount" hidden       field.
- if "X" is selected, set the amount = 2600 and disable the buttons otherwise, set the selected province and set the amount from 
  getFees method.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#myselect').change(function(){
                $('#province').val('');
  $('#amount').val('');
  var selectedOption = $(this).val();
  if(selectedOption === "X")
  {
   $('#amount').val("2600");
   $('#customButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $('#customButton2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  else
  {
   var amount = <?php echo getFees(selectedOption, 'sprice', $price); ?>;
   $('#province').val(selectedOption);
   $('#amount').val(amount);
   $('#customButton').removeAttr('disabled');
   $('#customButton2').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required name="prov" id="myselect" class="dropit" >
  <option value="X">Select ship to province</option>
  <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
  <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
  <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
  <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
  <option value="NL">Newfoundland/Labrador</option>
  <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
  <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
  <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
  <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
  <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
  <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
  <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
  <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
 </select>
                                
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="">  
 <input type="hidden" name="province" id="province" value="">
```

Comment: You should point out what changes you have made to the code and why to explain your answer

Comment: Added the explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
 var e = document.getElementById("myselect");
 var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 var province = document.getElementById("province");
 var amt = document.getElementById("amount");
    province.value = strUser;
    amt.value = getFees(province, 'sprice', $price);
}
```

```html
<select required name="prov" id="myselect" class="dropit" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="X">Select ship to province</option>
  <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
  <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
  <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
  <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
  <option value="NL">Newfoundland/Labrador</option>
  <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
  <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
  <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
  <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
  <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
  <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
  <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
  <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
 </select>
                                
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="">  
 <input type="hidden" name="province" id="province" value="">
```

Comment: Please, clarify what you did.